# Strategies for managing core data on Database

Tags: database

I would like to get some strategies for master data on a database with the following scenario:

There are the tables 'countries' and 'persons'. Each person has a country of origin. The following options are available to me when a person is to be created:

1. I start a query to the database, if the country already exists, I take its ID - otherwise I create the country and person on the tables.
2. I load the table 'countries' into memory at the start of the program and do the check.
3. I create a stored procedure on the database that implements this logic.

My thoughts on the three strategies:

1. Poor performance due to constant queries against the database
2. Good performance because the check happens in memory, but over long time the table could be quite large and the program would take a lot of memory.
3. Good performance because one query is created against the database and it manages everything. The dependency on the database could be detrimental. If the database should change, the stored procedure might need to be adjusted.

Are there other strategies to master such a scenario?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there so much data that you have to think about performance optimizations? Are you sure you have any performance trouble?

Comment: If you create a stored procedure - you still constantly call queries. That won't give you any performance boost.

Comment: There is a finite number of countries, holding a list of them all in memory is unlikely to be a significant amount of memory.